# What does a linear/geometric probability in time series mean?

Tags: time-series, probability, interpretation

In some discrete time series I analyzed I'd like to interpret whether there is a meaning to the observed probability model. The data is some discrete time series with a population of objects which at each instant are either on or off $x^{(i)}_t\in\{0,1\}$ ($i$ is object id and $t$ is time).

From the data it seems the probability fairly nicely fits (linear regression $R=0.97$; at $M=4$) the equation

$P(x^{(i)}_t=1|x^{(i)}_{t-1},\ldots,x^{(i)}_{t-M})=\sum_{k=1}^M aq^{-k}\cdot x^{(i)}_{t-k}$

with some parameters $a$ and $q$.

Do you think, there is any interpretation I can put into this - like a model or so (for example "every year this or that can happen with probability so and so and ...")? How would I approach such a thought?

Comment: I think this might be reformulated to become a markov model?